# How do I create a scaling step with a null lower bound of -infinity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I reading scaling policy [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html)

> There are a few rules for the step adjustments for your policy:
>
> The ranges of your step adjustments can't overlap or have a gap.
>
> Only one step adjustment can have a null lower bound (negative
>   infinity). If one step adjustment has a negative lower bound, then
>   there must be a step adjustment with a null lower bound.
>
> Only one step adjustment can have a null upper bound (positive
>   infinity). If one step adjustment has a positive upper bound, then
>   there must be a step adjustment with a null upper bound.
>
> The upper and lower bound can't be null in the same step adjustment.
>
> If the metric value is above the breach threshold, the lower bound is
>   inclusive and the upper bound is exclusive. If the metric value is
>   below the breach threshold, the lower bound is exclusive and the upper
>   bound is inclusive.

Why would I have a lower bound of "negative infinity" and how do I create one? When I edit my policies I see they have an upper bound of "+infinity" But I have never seen lower bound of "-infinity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this for a while, but I believe it when you choose an alarm based on when it is 'less than' something. Remove X instances. It is automatically shown when it makes sense in the scaling policy.

Autoscaling is very flexible. But, there is a bit of experimentation with AutoScaling to get it right, and useful. You'll know the performance profile of your app and how to accommodate it, or modify the app so that it scales better.